# Parentheses in Function and Closure

Tags: swift

I am bit confused on declaring parameter and return type in Swift.

does these parameter and return type have the same meaning? What is the use of those parentheses ()?

```
func myFunction() -> (()-> Int)

func myFunction() -> (Void-> Int)

func myFunction() -> Void-> Int
```

Answer (score 3):

First... `()` and `Void` are the same thing you have two different ways of writing the same thing.

Second... The `->` is right associative. So using parens as you have in your examples are meaningless, much like they are with an expression such as `a + (b * c)`. That expression is identical to `a + b * c`.

Basically, the three examples in your question all define a function that takes no parameters and returns a closure that takes no parameters and returns an Int.

Some more examples to help:

```
func myFuncA() -> () -> Int -> String {
    return { () -> Int -> String in return { (i: Int) -> String in String(i) } }
}

func myFuncB() -> () -> (Int -> String) {
    return { () -> Int -> String in return { (i: Int) -> String in String(i) } }
}

func myFuncC() -> (() -> Int) -> String {
    return { (f: () -> Int) in String(f()) }
}
```

In the above, myFuncA is identical to myFuncB, and they are both different than myFuncC.

myFuncA (and B) takes no parameters, and returns a closure. The closure it returns takes no parameters and returns another closure. This second closure takes an Int and returns a String.

myFuncC takes no parameters and returns a closure. The closure it returns takes a closure as a parameter and returns a String. The second closure takes no parameters and returns an Int.

Hopefully, writing it in Prose hasn't made it even more confusing.

Comment: when u explained that, for example:

"myFuncA (and B) takes no parameters, and returns a closure. The closure it returns takes no parameters and returns another closure. This second closure takes an Int and returns a String."

Does this mean that a closure (which takes no parameters) is  ()?

and the second closure is -> Int ->,  thus the second closure returns string, right?

Comment: A closure that takes no parameters and returns an `Int` is declared as `() -> Int` or `Void -> Int`. The latter is an uncommon use, but is valid. But yes, `myFuncA()` takes no parameters, and the closure it returns also takes no parameters.